# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta para la búsqueda de dos valores en un mismo registro de una BD? Tabla Pivot

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, sql

Estoy haciendo un módulo para agregar a favoritos, necesito verificar si existen los valores ya registrados antes de realizar una acción, quiero consultar en una tabla pivote si el registro existe, y de allí tomar decisión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito consultar antes de hacer el registro si los datos ya existe, ejemplo quisiera consultar si el usuario con ID 1 (user_id 1) ya agregó a favoritos el post 1 (post_id 1), si ya lo hizo eliminarlo, de lo contrario registrarlo. (En este ejemplo si lo hizo, el usuario con ID 1 agregó el Post con ID 1 a sus favoritos).

Ya tengo todo listo solo me falta hacer la consulta, no sé como verificar esos dos valores en un mismo registro.

Estoy trabajando con Laravel, gracias de antemano.